# In SQL, can we always write an inner join statement as a main query and subquery?

Tags: sql, join, subquery, inner-join

In SQL, can we always write an inner join statement as a main query and subquery?

For example,

```
 select * from gifts g where g.giftID in (select giftID from sentGifts);
```

can do a join and show the gifts sent in the sentGifts table, but it won't be able to show the sentTime because that is inside the subquery?

Comment: Try doing it when you join on multiple columns, and your database engine doesn't support tuple generation.

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676874/correlated-query-subquery-vs-join-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only use that if the condition is a single value.

You can't do that to a query like:

```
select *
from gifts g
inner join sentGifts s on s.giftType = g.giftType and s.giftDate = g.giftDate
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't rewrite all INNER JOINs like that.

Sometimes your inner join condition will involve more than one column and then IN won't necessarily work.

Also, sometimes the inner join condition will be a range or more complex expression where this query/subquery technique won't work at all, for example: finding overlapping intervals.